# In C++ why address of string, despite being in hexadecimal format, can't be stored in long int variable?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I have the following code :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    string texts[] = {"one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine", "ten"};
    return 0;
}
```

The code:

```
cout << &texts[0] << endl;
```

gives output:

```
0x7ffc7869f3c0
```

But,

```
long int address = &texts[0];
```

gives compile time error:

```
In function ‘int main()’:
5.cpp:9:29: error: invalid conversion from ‘std::__cxx11::string* {aka std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>*}’ to ‘long int’ [-fpermissive]
  long int address = &texts[0];
```

Why am I getting this error?

Comment: Because a pointer is not an integer (at least as far as C++ is concerned) - you should store the value in a variable of type `string *`.

Comment: Because there's no natural cast from a pointer value to a `long int`. You can force that though: `long int address = (long int)&texts[0];`

Comment: Why hexadecimal number is not integer?

Comment: Who said the address is in hexadecimal format? That may be the format in which `std::cout` chooses to emit it *after translation*, but it doesn't have *to be* in that format.

Comment: You can try casting in like (long int)&texts[0] to get it to work, but why on earth you need string address?

Comment: @Histar What do you mean _hexadecimal number_? That's how a pointer is represented at the output, not what it's type is.

Comment: An address is an address, **not** a hexadecimal number.

Comment: @Histar There's a difference between the type of an object (int, pointer to something, etc.) and the way it gets printed out to the screen. Just because a pointer gets printed in hex by default doesn't mean there is an type conversion from pointer to integer. There could well have been, but there isn't.

Comment: As  user0042 said, there's not language cast for pointer -> integer, so you must explicitly specify what you want to do with this value.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth OTOH C++ (and C) has many implicit type conversions, so I can see how one could expect a pointer to be convertible to  some large unsigned integer type.

Answer (score 0):

An address is an address, not a number. Arithmetic operations on addresses are generally meaningless (and pointer arithmetic is subtlely different), for example it makes no sense to multiply two addresses.

You might use `uintptr_t` or `intptr_t`. It is some integral type which can be casted to and from addresses. So you might code

```
 uintptr_t ia = (uintptr_t)(&texts[0]);
```

but you generally **should not**. On my Linux x86-64 an `uintptr_t` is equivalent to a 64 bits `unsigned long`.

Keep in mind that addresses are processor- and operating system- and compiler- so system- specific. Sometimes they vary between "identical" executions of the *same* program (read about [ASLR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization)). BTW, on some processors, addresses are more complex than a single number (for example on the 1980s x86 in 16 bits mode).

So if you care about [portable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_portability) C++ code (as you generally should), you need not cast addresses into integral types.

On the other hand, if you are coding something which is processor- and operating system- specific (e.g. an implementation of `new` or of `malloc` above low-level system calls), you will care about various bits inside addresses so you would cast it (in a non-portable manner). If you are coding the [virtual memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory) subsystem of some [operating system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system) kernel you'll care even much more about bits in addresses, etc...

Your `cout << &texts[0]` produces some *implementation specific* output which mostly makes sense for debugging purposes (but not much for something else). The C++11 standard is vague enough to permit any other output (my feeling is that an output like `pinkroses` for any address is conforming to the letter of the standard, but I could be wrong). So if you care about portability you should not depend on it (or on any concrete "number" an address looks like).

Even worse are the opposite cast, from `uintptr_t` to some pointer. They could be possible, but generally only on some *specific* system. And they are meaningful only in certain *particular* cases. Most numbers do not make sensible pointers (e.g. because your [virtual address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space) is never full or dense) so you should not cast them with great care.

A related concept is about [**undefined behavior**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). There are many interesting things to read and say about it.